# How can we upload image with other parameter in asp.net core API controller?

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, postman, iformfile

**This is my postman request =>**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRp49.png

**This is my controller method**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2ITY.png

Actually I have URL something like this way - **https://localhost:1111/api/user/1/avatar**
Now when I am hitting my endpoint then i am getting error like

"System.InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.FormFile'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor. Alternatively, give the 'avatar' parameter a non-null default value."

How can I upload image using above URL? I am using ASP.Net core 3.1 Web API.

Comment: Please don't post code as images; include the code as text instead, and format it using indentation or code fences (\`\`\`).

Comment: Seems the official docs says to use IFormFile? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 3):

You should change your `FormFile` type to `IFormFile` type, and then in postman, you should name your file parameter.

```
[HttpPost("user/{id=0}/{avatar}")]
[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
public IActionResult TestImage(int id, [FromForm]IFormFile avatar)
{
    return Ok();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[FromRoute]` to tag the `id` parameter without changing the consuming type:

```cs
[HttpPost("user/{id=0}/avatar")]
public IActionResult TestImage([FromRoute] int id, IFormFile avatar)
{
    return Ok($"id: {id}, avatar name: {avatar.FileName}");
}
```

The endpoint URL will be something like:

```
https://localhost:1111/TestUploadAvatar/user/324/avatar
```